# Manipulate a URL

Tags: php, html

I am looking to change an URL on my site when sending a PM to use a user I click on the PM icon and get the URL as:

```
index.php?page=usercp&do=pm&action=edit&uid=10&what=new&to=ObieWan
```

I need that URL to be able to work for any user to send ObieWan a PM but it won't work as it's using my uid of 10.
The link looks like as follows and is in a .php file:

```html
<a href="http://domain.com/index.php?page=usercp&do=pm&action=edit&uid=10&what=new&to=ObieWan"><font size="1">PM ObieWan</font></a>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please look here to learn, how to ask good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I do not understand the question: I assume PM is a private message, but is the URL a link?

Comment: Yes the url is a link a browser and yes, it is a personal message.

Answer (score 0):

Get the id of the current user and give it to the url like:

```
<?php
echo"
<a href='index.php?
page=usercp&do=pm&action=edit&uid='".$id."'&what=new&to=ObieWan'>This is the link
</a>";
?>
```

I have no idea about the rest of your code or database structure so you should get the ID from the user you want yourself. This is the way to pass the ID of the current user

Answer (score 0):

If its the uid that you want to change then you can use $_GET['uid'] to set it.